# One to many .WithOne null Fluent API EF Core 6 (code first)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I've configured one to many relation between entity User and Role in my DbContext.

When I'm creating user through POST I'm getting this response which is correct

```
{
  "userId": 3,
  "userName": "test",
  "passwordHash": "$2a$11$IGUiIWdyXuyHlVXGxBGrOu3fi3RqvlaE.ksn/9M9a3X5hIiXFb19e",
  "roleId": 1,
  "role": {
    "roleId": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "users": []
  },
  "offers": [],
  "responses": []
}
```

but when I will fetch user from DB then the role is null. RoleId is fine because its set as FK.

```
{
    "userId": 3,
    "userName": "test",
    "passwordHash": "$2a$11$IGUiIWdyXuyHlVXGxBGrOu3fi3RqvlaE.ksn/9M9a3X5hIiXFb19e",
    "roleId": 1,
    "role": null,
    "offers": [],
    "responses": []
  }
]
```

MyContext.cs

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(q => q.UserId);
            entity.Property(q => q.UserId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(q => q.UserName)
                .IsRequired();

            entity.Property(q => q.PasswordHash)
                .IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(u => u.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.RoleId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
        });
```

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(q => q.RoleId);
            entity.Property(q => q.RoleId)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(q => q.Name)
                .IsRequired();
            entity.HasIndex(q => q.Name)
                .IsUnique();
        });
```

User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public User(){}

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Role.cs

```
public class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Method for creating a user

```
public async Task<User> Create(string username, string password, string role)
    {
        EnsureNotNull(username, nameof(username));
        EnsureNotNull(password, nameof(password));
        EnsureNotNull(role, nameof(role));

        username = username.ToLower();

        if (_context.Users.Any(q => q.UserName == username))
            throw CreateException($"User {username} already exists.", null);

        var hash = _securityService.HashPassword(password);
        var userRole = await _roleService.GetRoleByName(role);
        var ret = new User {UserName = username, PasswordHash = hash, Role = userRole};

        _context.Users.Add(ret);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return ret;
    }
```

Method for getting users

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
    {
        return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
    }
```

I can just find instance via id I got from Db, but when I was working with database first EF Core, there was no problem like this.

Comment: `_context.Users.Include(u => u.Role).ToListAsync()`. EF Core do not load whole database because someone expects all navigation properties to be loaded. Also there is `AutoInclude` - you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding include worked

```
_context.Users.Include(u => u.Role).ToListAsync()
```